# Mongoose. Find all the fields in a collection with all the nested collections

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

We have 2 collections

1. Products
2. Photos

One document in Products collection looks like:

```
{
  id: ObjectID
  name: string
  price: number
  photo: ObjectID // A ref to Photos collection
}
```

A document in Photos collection:

```
{
  id: ObjectID
  path: string 
}
```

I want to find all the fields from Products collection with the ref fields.

**So I expect the result to be**:

```
{
  id: ObjectID
  name: string
  price: number
  photo: {
    id: ObjectID
    path: string
  }
}
```

When i use `Product.find()` it just results in:

```
{
  id: ObjectID
  name: string
  price: number
  photo: ObjectID
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you need to use the populate method.

You can use it as a function on the model itself:

`productSchema.pre(/^find/, function(next) {
  this.populate('photo').populate({
    path: 'path',
  });
  next();
});`

Make sure you call `next()` at the end or you will get stuck.

This is called a "pre" middleware in Mongoose and helps automatically retrieving data on any find method (findById, findOne etc.)

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html